# Return the date of the day under an if formula with Excel or VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba

I have two columns A and B and many lines with some specific tasks to be done. In column B, I have a drop-down list with the name of people who are scheduled for the task . And in column A, I want the date of the day the person signed off the task.

What should I do in VBA or in Excel so that, for example, when somebody signs off a task in the cell B11, A11 returns me the date of the day.

I have used the formula below in A11
=if (B11<>"", today(),"") but everytime i open the file the date is updated. So it doesn't allow me to keep track of everybody's work.

I tried with vba but couldn't write a function that gives me the right answer.
i'm pretty new at vba so i'm sorry if my question sounds stupid

Answer (score 3):

I spent 5min playing around with the below macro that I found [here](http://www.computing.net/answers/office/excel-enter-last-modified-date-into-a-cell/8851.html):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  Range("S" & Target.Row) = Date
End Sub
```

It will put the current Date in Column S, anytime anything in the selected row is changed.  It might be possible to adjust the macro to look for changes in a particular cell or column.